# Showing title above the first row in the dataset, expression in a switch statement SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, switch-statement, ssrs-2012

I am trying a switch where the first condition should be shown as a title of the first generated row.

```
=switch(RowNumber("GroupName") = 1, "0.",
Fields!FelTyp.Value = "D10" OR Fields!FelTyp.Value = "D15", "1.",
Fields!FelTyp.Value = "H20" OR Fields!FelTyp.Value = "H25", "2.",
Fields!FelTyp.Value = "I10" OR Fields!FelTyp.Value = "I15", "3.",
Fields!FelTyp.Value = "J10", "4.",
Fields!FelTyp.Value = "K10", "5.")
```

For the first condition I have also tried First(Fields!FelTyp.Value, "GroupName") but I dont know what to compare it with so all I get is an #ERROR for text. I just want to show the first text above the first row :/

I am redoing reports from crystal reports to ssrs and in Crystal reports it just says (suppress if not OnFirstRecord) which I am trying to turn around. The crystal statement "OnFirstRecord" returns true when the current record being evaluated is the first record in the report.

Thanks, Matilda!

Comment: Before using the switch function, check if all expressions can be evaluated (RowNumber("GroupName") and Fields!FelTyp.Value) from where your title should be shown. Is it part of the tablix that is bound to the dataset?

Comment: I have the expression as table header and checked that the table actually is connected to the dataset which it is. The expression works as it should without and with the first condition row. I just cant get the "0." to show :/ @WolfgangKais

Comment: So, if the expression works, then there is no problem? - Try just to use `=RowNumber("GroupName")` as expression, just to be sure. The header row should be in the same group as the row with that "number 1".

Comment: The first row doesnt seem to work cause no "0." is showing. I have  done a temporary solution though by only having a textbox but that wont work in the long run.  @WolfgangKais

Comment: You are trying to check whether you're in the first record... but you do this in the table header. The header will never be in any record. Therefore, use a row that belongs to the group ("GroupName").